# Vim not changing tabstop to 4 after configurations in ~/.vimrc (details included)

Tags: vim

Intended behavior is to have every time I press tab the system outputs 4 spaces for me. Currently it outputs a tab that is equal to 8 spaces of length.

Here's my configuration in ~/.vimrc

```
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set smarttab
```

(there's currently no other content in the file)

Here's what happens with relevant commands I see other people in other stackoverflow posts

```
:verbose set tabstop?
tabstop=8
```

```
:verbose setlocal ts? sts? et? sw?
tabstop=8
softtabstop=0
noexpandtab
shiftwidth=8
```

To see if any other program is overriding the vim setting, I would appreciate any suggestions on where to start.

The only significant thing I can think about, is I have vim aliased to nvim. That is

```
which nvim
/user/bin/nvim
which vim
vim: aliased to nvim
```

yet in the nvim file I have the same settings and get the same response running verbose set tabstop? etc.

Comment: Neovim doesn't read your `.vimrc` so there is no reason to expect options you put there to be picked up. If you are using Neovim, then use its dedicated configuration file and simplify this question by leaving Vim and `.vimrc` out of it. If you are using Vim, then the Neovim stuff is irrelevant and can be left out.

Answer (score 0):

neovim's configuration file is not located in `~/.nvimrc`, but in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`.

the suggested configuration:

```
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```